# Insert character in column 80 of multiple lines of a textfile

Tags: vim, sed, awk

I have written a multi-line C macro and for readability reasons I would like to insert the character '\' in column 80 of each line. An example will probably help understand what I need.
Suppose that the macro is originally like this:

```
#define MY_MACRO \
expression \
a_longer_expression \
 \
a_super_jumbo_size_expression \
macro_ends_here
```

I would like the final result to be like this:

```
#define MY_MACRO                     \
expression                           \
a_longer_expression                  \
                                     \
a_super_jumbo_size_expression        \
macro_ends_here
```

So each line should be filled with spaces from the last non-space character up to column 79 and then insert '\' in column 80, including empty lines.

Is this possible using vim, sed or awk? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

select the range you want and enter the following ex command:

```
:'<,'>s/\s*\\$/\=repeat(' ', 80-col('.')).'\'
```

Which substitutes the whitespace and \ at the end of the line with an expression which repeats a space up until column 80 and then appends a `\` character. It'll append 0 spaces if your line is > 80 characters, which may not be what you want, in which case change the 80 to 79 and add a space to the string: `' \'`

Answer (score 5):

one possibility in vim playing with `g:` and `ve`:

```
:g/\\$/set ve=all|normal $x80|r\
```

if you want to set your `ve` back to `""` after the modification:

```
:g/\\$/set ve=all|exec 'normal $x80|r\'|set ve=""
```

or **awk**

```
 awk '/\\$/{sub(/\\$/,"");$0=sprintf("%s%"80-length($0)"s",$0,"\\")}7' file
```

Comment: The awk will add a backslash to lines such as `macro_ends_here` try `awk '/\\$/{sub(/.$/,"");printf "%s%"80-length"s",$0,"\\\n";next}1' file`

Comment: @sudo_O I found it too, already fixed. :) and your suggestion will print empty lines. thx anyway

Comment: Neat awk, but there is only a minor problem. It inserts the '\' at column 79 instead of 80. This is fixed by changing `...80-length...` to `...81-length...`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat file
#define MY_MACRO \
expression \
a_longer_expression \
 \
a_super_jumbo_size_expression \
macro_ends_here

$ awk 'sub(/\\$/,"") { $0 = sprintf("%-79s\\",$0) } 1' file
#define MY_MACRO                                                               \
expression                                                                     \
a_longer_expression                                                            \
                                                                               \
a_super_jumbo_size_expression                                                  \
macro_ends_here
```

Comment: !! why I forgot the minus!! +1

Comment: @Kent FYI you can also use a `*` placeholder in the format string for the padding value as an argument so you don't need to break up your format string to use a variable number of spaces, e.g. `sprintf("%s%*s",$0,80-length($0),"\\")` instead of `sprintf("%s%"80-length($0)"s",$0,"\\")`

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne 'if(/\\$/){s/[\s]*\\//g;printf "%-79s\\\n",$_}else{print}' your_file
```

if you want to change the file inplace :

```
perl -i -lne 'if(/\\$/){s/[\s]*\\//g;printf "%-79s\\\n",$_}else{print}' your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

I would this with the [Tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) plugin

```
:Tabularize /\\/l50r0
```